# If 100 of one item costs $1200 How do I find what 1 of that item costs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The title is just an example and I didn't know what to call it. If, for example, 100 of an item costs $1200 then how much would one of that item cost?

Comment: What's the discount for buying in bulk?

Comment: Why down vote? Is there any guideline that disallows such questions?

Comment: @baharampuri:  I'm not the down voter, but a down vote does not mean the subject matter of a Question is "disallowed".  If you hover a mouse over the voting arrows, you'll see a tool tip that gives the message "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: I am aware of it, but what amount of research one can expect for this question which obviously is coming from a beginner. Here clearly the OP is asking for the method which was not introduced to him/her which is why he/she says it's an example.

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1.

$$100x = 1200 \implies x = \frac{1200}{100} = 12$$

Thus, a unit costs $12\text{ \$}$.

---

### Method 2.

Let $N_1 = 100$ be the number of units bought initially, and $P_1 = 1200$ be the price for the $N_1$ items.

Let $N_2 = 1$ be the number of units one wants to buy, and $P_2 =\:?$ be the price for $N_2$ units.

Now you should find the ratio between price and number of units:
$$r=\frac{P_1}{N_1}$$
$$r=\frac{1200}{100} = 12$$

Now multiply by $N_2$ units to get the final price:
$$P_2=N_2\cdot r$$
$$P_2=1 \cdot 12 = 12 \text{ \$ (dollars)}$$

---

### Method 3. - The rule of three

$$100 \text{ units   ............    1200 \$}$$
$$1   \text{ unit    ............    n \$}$$

$$n = \frac{1200 \cdot 1}{100}$$
$$n = 12$$

---

*However, I think one should be offered a discount for buying $100$ units over just $1$ item...*

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $p$ be the price of one item. If 100 of them costs 1200 then 
the following equation hold $100\times p=1200$.

Are you able to find the value of $p$?